# C# Master Detail View - Reverting unsaved changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm creating CRUD application in C# with Caliburn.Micro and I have some Master Detail View that looks like that:

[image]

What i want to achieve is, when i make some changes(for example i change capacity from 47 to 50), and then select the other place, let's say *Place 4* and select *Place 5* again my capacity will be 47, not 50 like it is now.

I was thinking about OneTime binding, and manually firing binding to the viewmodel then, but viewModel should not have been aware of the view, so that seems like a bad idea. My code below.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Places"
          Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
          Width="290"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" SelectionMode="Single">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Place" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=OneTime}" MinWidth="150"
                            Width="SizeToCells" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
<Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"
      Width="290" Height="210"
      HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Content="ID"
           Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Place*"
           Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Address*"
           Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Capacity*"
           Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Comments"
           Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

    <TextBox x:Name="SelectedPlace_Id"
             Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
             IsEnabled="False" />
    <TextBox x:Name="SelectedPlace_Name"
             Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox x:Name="SelectedPlace_Address"
             Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
             Height="55" VerticalAlignment="Top"
             TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <TextBox x:Name="SelectedPlace_Capacity"
             Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox x:Name="SelectedPlace_Comments"
             Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Height="55"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</Grid>
<Button x:Name="DeletePlace" Content="Delete"
        Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"
        Width="100" Height="30" Margin="0 0 110 0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
<Button x:Name="SavePlace" Content="Save"
        Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"
        Width="100" Height="30" Margin="0 0 5 0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

ViewModel:

```
    class PlacesTabViewModel : TabViewModel
{ 
    #region Fields

    private BindableCollection<Place> _places;
    private Place _selectedPlace;

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public PlacesTabViewModel()
    {
        using (var ctx = new DbCtx(App.DatabasePath))
        {
            _places = new BindableCollection<Place>(ctx.Places.OrderBy(p => p.Name));
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Places";
    }

    #endregion

    #region Events

    public bool CanDeletePlace => _selectedPlace != null;

    public bool CanSavePlace => (_selectedPlace != null) && _selectedPlace.IsValid();

    public void DeletePlace()
    {
        using (var ctx = new DbCtx(App.DatabasePath))
        {
            try
            {
                ctx.Entry(SelectedPlace).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                //TODO: Error
                return;
            }

            Places.Remove(SelectedPlace);

            NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(Places));
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanDeletePlace);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanSavePlace);
        }
    }

    public void SavePlace()
    {
        using (var ctx = new DbCtx(App.DatabasePath))
        {
            try
            {
                ctx.Places.Attach(_selectedPlace);
                ctx.Entry(_selectedPlace).State = EntityState.Modified;
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch
            {
                //TODO: Error
            }

            NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(Places));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public BindableCollection<Place> Places
    {
        get { return _places; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _places)
            {
                _places = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(Places));
            }
        }
    }

    public Place SelectedPlace
    {
        get { return _selectedPlace; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedPlace)
            {
                _selectedPlace = value;

                if (_selectedPlace != null) 
                {
                    _selectedPlace.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
                    {
                        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanSavePlace);
                    };
                }

                NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(SelectedPlace));
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanDeletePlace);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanSavePlace);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

ViewModel for the MainWindow

```
class MainWindowViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    #region Fields

    private BindableCollection<TabViewModel> _tabs = new BindableCollection<TabViewModel>();

    #endregion

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _tabs.Add(new PlacesTabViewModel());
    }

    #region Properties

    public BindableCollection<TabViewModel> Tabs
    {
        get { return _tabs; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _tabs)
            {
                _tabs = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(Tabs));
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: There ain't no magic, you have to write it.  Bind to SelectedItem, and watch for a change. When you select a Place, you get your change notification.  Clone the object.  Place it into a CurrentEdit property bound to the editor.  Unsaved clones go away if you switch SelectedItem without hitting Save.  When you hit Save, take the clone, look for the original in the ItemsSource collection, and switch them.  Or, copy the property values from the clone, either or.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF doesn't know Normal properties. You either have to make it a dependency property, or in your case, your VM has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. when the value changes it will automatically updated.

May be you didn't applied INotifyPropertyChanged property for **SelectedPlace_Capacity**.

I think that this is the issue.